# Set working directory in `VBoxManage guestcontrol run`

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I'm using:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol "Windows 10" --username "john" run "Z:\\path\\to\\bin.exe"
```

The command gets executed but I need to run it in a specified directory.

Is there a way to set the working directory in `VBoxManage guestcontrol run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your guest is Windows, try using [`CMD.EXE`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) and [`START`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html), something like

```sh
VBoxManage guestcontrol "Windows 10" \
    run \
    --username "john" \
    --exe "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" \
    -- cmd.exe /C "START /D Z:\\path\\to Z:\\path\\to\\bin.exe"
```

should suffice. You may need to modify it to suit your needs.

`CMD.EXE` supports `/C` to run given command and terminate, in which we run `START`.

`START` supports `/D` to run a command in a specified directory, in this case we're using `Z:\path\to`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Btw, another solution is to execute a .bat file that changes to the expected directory and executes the command

Comment: yeah, was thinking about that too, but if you're running it in headless mode, then it's easier to just run `START /D` rather than remoting to the Windows guest, create a batch file, and run it from the host.